# Node process does not exit with mongoose index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This code exits correctly by running `node my-script.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const FooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
})

const Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/foo')
mongoose.disconnect()
```

But this one does not:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const FooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
})
FooSchema.index({name: 'text'})

const Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/foo')
mongoose.disconnect()
```

The error is:

> MongoError: topology was destroyed

The only difference here is that I use `index`function. Is there a way to "execute" the `index` function before anything else in order to exit cleanly?

*Side note: I want to be sure that after this line: `FooSchema.index({name: 'text'})` the index is actually created.*

Comment: Doesn't mongoose emit an `index` event when the index is created?

Comment: @Mark_M Ok thank you! Still, adding `Foo.on('index', function(error) { console.log(error)})` displays `undefined` and does not change the error message. My question is: "Is there a way to "execute" the index function before anything else in order to exit cleanly?"

Comment: You can place in the callback handler whatever you want to happen after

Comment: @maioman Ok thank you! I'm not sure I understand your comment. I don't want to do something on callback, I would like to execute the index function then continue my script execution normally. Continuing the script in a callback is not an option (and may not work either). But maybe I misunderstood something. You could post you comment as an anwser...

Comment: May be this doc will help http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving is caused by disconnecting while doing a write operation.

If you wait for `'index'` event to disconnect you should solve the issue:

```
FooSchema.on('index', function(error) {
  mongoose.disconnect()
  // then to exit the script use 
  process.exit()
});
```

Comment: `FooSchema.on('index', function(error) {mongoose.disconnect()})` never appends and the script runs infinitely.

Comment: Thanks again! Even with an exit, nothing appends (it seems it nevers enter into the callback).

Comment: Instead of creating the index try to make an `insert` in the db, and check if it gets written correctly

Comment: Hum you are right. The same problem occurs with: `Foo.create({name: 'text'})`